# mongodb : Return array of values into a variable

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I come from RDBMS background and finding it difficult to get myself aligned with mongodb and have been struggling to generate just the array of values. Once i get the array, I need to use these array values in $condition clause of aggregate function using $in

I have a collection which returns me :

```
db.Users.find({user_id : 1623}, { "Friends" : 1, _id : 0})
```

And content:

```
{ "Friends" : [ 708, 784, 1495, 212, 1918, 2007, 1439, 1634, 649 ] }
```

I would only require the array of values than document type:

```
[ 708, 784, 1495, 212, 1918, 2007, 1439, 1634, 649 ]
```

Is there a easier way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.distinct()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) instead, as it basically just returns an array:

```js
db.Users.distinct("Friends", { "user_id": 1623 })
```

But I really think you a being pedantic, and should just accept the result "as is" and use the array for the field instead.

Comment: @Alwyn On this site "thanks" is called [accepting the answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Helps others know that this is what works as a solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly ask for Friends array. ie: Assuming user_id is unique:

```
var arr = db.Users.findOne({user_id : 1623}).Friends;
```

Comment: Even this works.. Bieng a rdbms guy i prefer distinct :-)

Comment: That is fine, I am an RDBMS guy too, but be aware they are not the same thing. In this case, distinct might be what you want though.